# Difference between hook_node_type() and hook_nodeapi()

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

I'm trying to understand the difference between **[hook_node_type](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_node_type/6)** and **[hook_nodeapi](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_nodeapi/6)**

I've tried to use `hook_node_type` with the `story` node and a simple `dsm` but got nothing.

```
function mymod_node_story($op, $info){
   dsm($info);
}
```

Comment: The implementation of `hook_node_type()` for the module mymod.module is `mymod_node_type()`, and it's called for any content type, independently from the module that implements the content type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`hook_node_type` is made to hook into when a node type is changed. Fx if you want to allow comments on node type story etc.

`hook_nodeapi` is used to be able to hook into the different processes that can happen to an actual node, like when a node is saved, when it's being viewed etc.

There's not a hook for specific nodes, but instead you usually do something like this.

```
function module_nodeapi(&$node, $op, $teaser = NULL, $page = NULL) {
  if ($node->type == 'story') {
    switch ($op) {
      case 'load':
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I see. Is there a hook that's identical to `hook_nodeapi` but targets only a specific node type? Something that would look like `hook_nodeapi_story` if it existed.

Answer (score 3):

`hook_node_type()` is invoked each time a content type is deleted, or renamed. The purpose of the hook is to rename the Drupal variables used for the content type (which is automatically done for any form field included in the content type edit form, from [`node_type_form_submit()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/node_type_form_submit/6)), or to delete the Drupal variables containing values for the content type that has been deleted.

`hook_nodeapi()` is invoked for each node when it's loaded from the database, the node edit form is shown, the node is visualized, when the node is being indexed from the search module, when a RSS feed, or the node is saved. A module should implement `hook_nodeapi()` to alter nodes for content types implemented by other modules.